Bulk importing data from csv files with many differing columns but similar data into PostgreSQL
I want to write a script for mass importing hundreds of csv files into PostgreSQL with differing columns/formatting
How do you bulk import data that has differing columns/formats into another table on postgresql using a csv file?
For example this code below outlines how to bulk import data into SQL, yet do not know how import data that has different columns.
So how would we modify the code below to accomplish this task? I am new to postgresql so please pardon my stupidity.
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO

# Database connection parameters
db_params = {
    "dbname": "your_database",
    "user": "your_username",
    "password": "your_password",
    "host": "your_host",
    "port": "your_port",
}

# File path to your CSV
csv_file = "your_file.csv"
table_name = "your_table_name"

# Connect to PostgreSQL
conn = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Step 1: Read CSV into Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Step 2: Create table dynamically
columns = df.columns
col_str = ", ".join([f'"{col}" TEXT' for col in columns])  # Assuming TEXT for simplicity
create_table_query = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} ({col_str});"
cur.execute(create_table_query)
conn.commit()

# Step 3: Use COPY to load the data
buffer = StringIO()
df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False)  # Write DataFrame to buffer without header
buffer.seek(0)

# COPY data into the table
copy_query = f"COPY {table_name} ({', '.join(columns)}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV"
cur.copy_expert(copy_query, buffer)
conn.commit()

# Close connections
cur.close()
conn.close()

print(f"Data from {csv_file} has been successfully imported into {table_name}.")


I tried to aggregate all column names and was able to create a file with all column names yet was unsure of how to align the data with the columns.

What exactly do you mean by "differing columns"?  Do you mean the csv files have different numbers of columns, i.e. one csv file might have six columns while another file has ten?  Do you mean the csv files have different headers for what is otherwise the same column?

Yes I mean both - For example, one csv file may have 3 columns that have headers x, y, z while the other csv file would have 4 columns with headers x, a, y, z.

Are you expecting to import all of the csv files into a single table, or each file into a separate table?

I am expected to import all csv files into a single table

The idea is not bad, but if I understand correctly, you copied the "hundreds of CSV" into one file? This is a bad idea! You have to solve it in an outer iteral to go through the files and create tables with the same file name in a row. The number of columns in the CSV is determined by your program.
You should build the cycle in such a way that you enter a path where the files are and go through them and create the table for each file and upload the data.

I did not upload all the csv's into one file - although I was considering this idea so thank you for guiding me out of it. I am just confused about how the program would be able to allocate data into columns that have different names and keep the other columns null

Okay so here is what I did and it worked!
import os
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO

# Database connection details
db_params = {
    "dbname": "xxx",
    "user": "xxx",
    "password": "xxx",
    "host": "xxx",
    "port": xxx
}
excel_folder_path = "xxx"
table_name = "xxx"


# Connect to PostgreSQL
conn = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Function to create the table dynamically
def create_table_from_csv(file_path, table_name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    columns = df.columns
    col_defs = []

    for col in columns:
        if pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df[col]):
            col_defs.append(f'"{col}" INTEGER')
        elif pd.api.types.is_float_dtype(df[col]):
            col_defs.append(f'"{col}" FLOAT')
        elif pd.api.types.is_bool_dtype(df[col]):
            col_defs.append(f'"{col}" BOOLEAN')
        elif pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[col]):
            col_defs.append(f'"{col}" TIMESTAMP')
        else:
            col_defs.append(f'"{col}" TEXT')

    col_str = ", ".join(col_defs)
    create_table_query = f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name} ({col_str});"
    cur.execute(create_table_query)
    conn.commit()
    print(f"Table {table_name} has been created based on {file_path}.")

# Function to alter the table to include missing columns
def add_missing_columns(df, table_name):
    # Get existing table columns from PostgreSQL
    cur.execute(f"SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '{table_name}';")
    existing_columns = set(row[0] for row in cur.fetchall())

    # Find missing columns
    missing_columns = set(df.columns) - existing_columns
    for col in missing_columns:
        if pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df[col]):
            col_type = "INTEGER"
        elif pd.api.types.is_float_dtype(df[col]):
            col_type = "FLOAT"
        elif pd.api.types.is_bool_dtype(df[col]):
            col_type = "BOOLEAN"
        elif pd.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype(df[col]):
            col_type = "TIMESTAMP"
        else:
            col_type = "TEXT"

        # Add the missing column to the table
        alter_query = f'ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN "{col}" {col_type};'
        cur.execute(alter_query)
        conn.commit()
        print(f"Added column {col} ({col_type}) to table {table_name}.")

# Function to import CSV data into the table
def import_csv_to_table(file_path, table_name):
    # Read the CSV into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

    # Remove extra spaces from column names
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()  # Remove extra spaces

    # Ensure all table columns are present
    add_missing_columns(df, table_name)

    # Align DataFrame columns to match table columns
    cur.execute(f"SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '{table_name}';")
    table_columns = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]
    
    # Add any missing columns with NULL values
    for col in table_columns:
        if col not in df.columns:
            df[col] = None  # Add missing columns with NULL values

    df = df[table_columns]  # Ensure column order matches the table

    # Use COPY to load the data
    buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(buffer, index=False, header=False)  # Default is comma-delimited
    buffer.seek(0)

    # Construct the COPY query
    columns_str = ", ".join([f'"{col}"' for col in table_columns])
    copy_query = f"COPY {table_name} ({columns_str}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV"

    # Debugging: print buffer content and query
    print(f"Buffer content:\n{buffer.getvalue()}")
    print(f"Executing query: {copy_query}")

    cur.copy_expert(copy_query, buffer)
    conn.commit()
    print(f"Data from {file_path} has been successfully imported into {table_name}.")


# Process all CSV files in the folder
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(csv_folder) if f.endswith('.csv')]
if not csv_files:
    print("No CSV files found in the folder.")
else:
    # Create the table from the first file
    first_csv = os.path.join(csv_folder, csv_files[0])
    create_table_from_csv(first_csv, table_name)

    # Import all files, dynamically adjusting the table as needed
    for filename in csv_files:
        file_path = os.path.join(csv_folder, filename)
        print(f"Processing file: {file_path}")
        import_csv_to_table(file_path, table_name)

# Close connections
cur.close()
conn.close()

print("All CSV files have been success")


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
